# How do I make jQuery from a ES6 Bundle available to external scripts loaded in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

On a website, I bundle all the javascript with Gulp into one bundle file. This includes jQuery, which I import into all the JS files that require it.

I include the Google Tag Manager (GTM) directly in the HTML. However, some of the custom tags require jQuery, which is undefined according to browser console output. I assume jQuery is not exposed outside the bundle.

**How do I expose jQuery from the bundle so external scripts such as GTM can use it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

Got the idea from jqfundamental's [jQuery Basics Guide](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics):

```
import $ from 'jquery';
// make jquery available to all imports using `window` to load jQuery
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
```

With these two lines, the jQuery version loaded via `import` (in my case the one I specified in my Node package.json) will be assigned to the `window` object, from which most jQuery plugins as well as GTM custom tags load jQuery.

I put this statement on top of my main js file. This way I make sure that all imported jQuery plugins can access jQuery via `window`, as well.

---

#### Why this works

For everyone not completely aware of it: All properties of the `window` object are globally available with their key name:

```
window.foo = 'someValue';
console.log(foo); 
// outputs 'someValue' even if used in a different scope/file/module
```

---

#### If this doesn't work

Check the last line of your plugin code: Some plugins load jQuery from `this.jQuery` instead of `window.jQuery`.

Usually, `this` in JS scripts on the top level points to `window`, so above approach works. However, in ES6 modules - and as such the bundle code is run in the browser - `this` is `undefined` (see this [exploringjs table](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_browsers-scripts-versus-modules) for reference).

I haven't found a good solution other than adjusting the plugin code to use `window.jQuery`. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611940/can-i-set-this-for-a-module-loaded-with-require-in-node) (unanswered at the time of writing).

---

#### Reason for this issue

Stumbled upon [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/254) which explains the reason for this behavior quite well: The jQuery code contains a conditional testing for `module` being defined and an object:

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ){
  // set jQuery in `module`
} else {
  // set jQuery in `window`
}
```

In Nodejs, `module` is an object even in the browser, thus jQuery is not globally available by default, but only in the current scope of the import.